# PointPlacemark label is not hidden by the terrain

Tags: labeling, worldwind, nasa

I am facing this problem where the label for the pointplacemark using the NASA worldwind API is not hidden behind terrain. The symbol hides but the label doesn't. It uses javax.media.opengl.GL and TextRenderer. If anyone has any idea about this problem, please share your views and do let me know if you need any other input.

You can see the problem in a similar thread at:
http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?42600-PointPlacemark-label-is-not-hidden-by-the-terrain

Comment: Found that part unnecessary so removed

Comment: I further found that TextRenderer renders label at screenposition(Vec4 : the projection of the place-point in the viewport (on the screen)), so thats why it does not consider elevation. Is there any other way of doing it so that it considers elevation and hides behind the terrain as the symbol does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can hide it. Check your texture model with :

```
worldWindowGLJPanel.setValue(AVKey.USE_TRANSPARENT_TEXTURES,true);
```

If it is falseyou the pointplacemark will not visible behind the texture. If you can provide sample code, I can be more helpful.